# Can I simplify selection sort in C?

Tags: c, selection-sort

Selection sort in C usually written in the form of the following code below, introducing a `min_pos` variable in which is stored the index of the minimum number of the array in a particular step of a `for` loop:

```
void selectionsort(int A[], int n)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < n - 1; i++)
    {
        int min_pos = i;
        for (int j = i + 1; j < n; j++)
        {
            if (A[j] < A[min_pos])
            {
                min_pos = j;
            }
            if (min_pos != i)
            {
                int temp;
                temp = A[i];
                A[i] = A[min_pos];
                A[min_pos] = temp;
            }
        }
    }
    return;
}
```

But, Is it necessary to introduce this variable when we can get the same result using the following code?

```
void selectionsort(int A[], int n)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < n - 1; i++)
    {
        for (int j = i + 1; j < n; j++)
        {
            if (A[j] < A[i])
            {
                int temp;
                temp = A[i];
                A[i] = A[j];
                A[j] = temp;
            }
        }
    }
    return;
}
```

Comment: [selection sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selection_sort) does **one** swap only per outer loop. `for (i) { for (j) { <find smallest> } swap() }`

Comment: @AtmaneLee: you can accept one of the answers by clicking on the grey checkmark below its score.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a wondeful explanation (unmodified) by owner of a youtube channel named : portfolio courses

Wow - this is an awesome question!  :-)  So the above algorithm will work too, but it just sorts the array in a different way.  As to why we might not do it this way:

1. This is a video on selection sort, and the above algorithm is not selection sort (even though it's close to it).  In selection sort we find the smallest/largest element in the unsorted portion and swap it with the leftmost unsorted algorithm.  Other approaches may also work, but they will not be a selection sort anymore.  The above approach will do many, many more swaps than required.
2. For comparison's sake, I modified this code here to test the two different algorithms: https://github.com/portfoliocourses/c-example-code/blob/main/selection_sort.c.  I modified the code to count the number of swaps required (see the modifications below for Selection Sort and this New Algorithm you've made).  Selection Sort required only 6 swaps, where as the code above required 31 swaps.

One of the reasons why Selection Sort is used is that it's helpful when the cost of performing a swap in terms of time is high: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithm#Selection_sort.  I know it's Wikipedia, but see this quote: "It does no more than n swaps, and thus is useful where swapping is very expensive."

Selection Sort:

```
  int num_swaps = 0;
  for (int i = 0; i < length - 1; i++)
  {
    // find the position of the minimum element in the unsorted portion of 
    // the array
    int min_pos = i;
    for (int j = i + 1; j < length; j++)
      if (a[j] > a[min_pos]) min_pos = j;
    
    // if that element is NOT the element at index i, then swap that element 
    // with the element at index i
    if (min_pos != i)
    {
      int temp = a[i];
      a[i] = a[min_pos];
      a[min_pos] = temp;
      num_swaps++;
    }
  }
```

New Algorithm:

```
int num_swaps = 0;
for (int i=0; i<length-1; i++)
{
  for (int j=i+1; j<length; j++)
  {
      if(a[i]>a[j])
      {
          int temp;
          temp = a[i];
          a[i] = a[j];
          a[j] = temp;
          num_swaps++;
      }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Both functions achieve the same result but neither one is a correct implementation of [selection sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selection_sort).  They implement a less efficient algorithm called [exchange sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithm#Exchange_sort).

For selection sort, a single swap should be performed for each element in the array. This was probably the purpose of the `min_pos` variable in the first function.

Here is a modified version:

```
void selectionsort(int A[], int n)
{
   for (int i = 0; i < n - 1; i++)
   {
       int min_pos = i;
       for (int j = i + 1; j < n; j++)
       {
           if (A[j] < A[min_pos])
           {
               min_pos = j;
           }
       }
       if (min_pos != i)
       {
           int temp = A[i];
           A[i] = A[min_pos];
           A[min_pos] = temp;
       }
   }
}
```

Comment: I appreciate your help !

Answer (score 0):

I think both algorithms are not particularly efficient, a more efficient way to write them would be as below:

```
void selectionsort(int A[], int n)
{
   for (int i = 0; i < n - 1; i++)
   {
       int min_pos = i;
       for (int j = i + 1; j < n; j++)
       {
           if (A[j] < A[min_pos])
           {
               min_pos = j;
           }
       }
       if (min_pos != i)
       {
           int temp;
           temp = A[i];
           A[i] = A[min_pos];
           A[min_pos] = temp;
       }
   }
   return;
}
```

Notice how the min_pos variable is used as a temporary storage for the swapping position. This is beneficial since the swapping requires three operations while using min_pos only requires one operation.